# Hide React Navigation only for Android Platform

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In order to hide `React Navigation` I'm using the code below:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };
```

Fortunately it's working fine, but the problem appears when I want to differentiate between android and iOS based on their different UX, I want to hide the Navigation bar only in android platform:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    header: Platform.OS === 'android' ? null: /* don't know what to write here :( */,
  };
```

The piece I've commented above is executed for iOS. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to use default header, not a custom one? Then you need to import `Header` from **react-navigation**:

```
import { Header } from 'react-navigation';
```

Then you apply it as default header with correct props:

```
static navigationOptions = {
  header: (headerProps) => Platform.OS === 'android' ? null : <Header {...headerProps} />
};
```

This should do it.